# How can i pass data between reactjs pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following config in `App.jsx`

```
<Route path='/Main' component={Main} />
<Route path='/Details' component={Details} />
```

So when a user selects the `Details` , they will be taken to the `Details` page. But I want to pass a few parameters and their values from the main page
How can i do that ?